# FireWire Target Disk Mode shows wrong storage capacity

Tags: hard-drive, target-disk-mode

Update: I was mistaken about the hard drive size, there was no corruption of the disk nor a mistake in the displayed size.

This is a question of many parts. The gist is captured by the title: I mounted using target disk mode and the capacity (of what should be a 160.04 gb drive) is 60.01 gb. The question is, how is this possible?

I tried to wipe the drive of an old MacBook and install Lubuntu. The install itself failed because I'd accidentally corrupted the boot disk, leaving me with a non-functional laptop. In order to solve the problem, I decided to clone a functional MacBook drive onto it, then start over with a new boot disk. (A clean install without an OS was not working, I'm hoping this will)

I did do a web search, I found someone with a similar issue who was mounting because they had hard drive problems. I did not have hard drive problems to begin with, does this indicate that I do now? If so, what about a bad install would decrease the capacity of a hard drive? How does it actually decrease the capacity of an HDD?

EDIT: some terminal output

```
admin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *160.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            159.7 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *60.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            59.7 GB    disk1s2

admin$ sudo gpt -r show disk1
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  116538416      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  116948056     262151         
  117210207         32         Sec GPT table
  117210239          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list`and `sudo gpt -r show diskX` (with diskX: the disk identifier of the target mode MB e.g disk2) entered in Terminal to your question. Edit the result into your question instead of posting a comment!

Comment: I should add that cloning the 160gb disk onto the 60 gb disk is 90% done and hasn't thrown an error. Perhaps it's accessing the rest of the disk even through it doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: Are you sure that the old MB really had a 160 GB disk inside? [MacBooks](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/index-macbook.html). Please add the precise MacBook model (e.g. MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.4 13" (White-08)).

Comment: I have about 20 of the exact same MacBooks, the one I'm restoring it from is precisely the same (and has a 160 gb drive). Moreover, when I initially installed I didn't notice anything out of the ordinary. (MacBook 1,1 Core Duo 1.83 GHz: MacBook "Core Duo" 1.83 13". But it has 1 gb of ram and a 160 gb hdd so I'm guessing it was purchased with options?)

Comment: According to everymac **no** MacBook1,1 was sold with a 160 GB disk by default. So it would have to be a BTO or a later "upgraded" MacBook to contain a 160 GB disk.

Comment: You've convinced me, it really was just 60 gb. It's curious I didn't notice when I first began. The final bit that convinced me (the cloning worked, it booted back to OS X) is that it still says 60 gb and the brand is different. The 160 says WDC and this one is a Toshiba. I'll have to keep an eye out for that in the other machines. Thanks!